# Adding new conditions to strategy.exit() - Can't get it to work

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to add extra conditions to exit trades using strategy.exit() but I can't get it to work right/don't know how.

Right now, my exits are set up using take profit (TP)(with trailing) and stop loss (SL) percentages based on the average percentage true range (APTR) and it's working great. But I basically want to add a condition that will also sell if the ema(9) drops below the ema(15) OR if the ema (15) drops below the ema(30).

So basically, the sell conditions would be:

- Take Profit (TP) % is met (w/ trailing) **--> existing**
- Stop Loss (SL) % is hit **--> existing**
- when = ema9 < ema15 OR ema15 < ema30 **--> need to add**

Below is the existing strategy.entry() & strategy.exit() code that is working.

How do I add the new condition without changing anything???

```
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, 10.0, when = Buy)

strategy.exit("Sell", "Buy",
   trail_points = (close * (APTR/100*TP)) / syminfo.mintick,
   trail_offset = (close * (APTR/100*0.5)) / syminfo.mintick,
   loss = (close * (APTR/100*SL)) / syminfo.mintick)
```

Could not get extra conditions to work.

Answer (score 0):

You add a condition that trigger another exit
(You place it after your entry and your first exit) :

```
if (ema9 < ema15) or (ema15 < ema30)
    strategy.exit("SellFromEma", "Buy")
```

Comment: Should be `strategy.close()`.